# kendo Ui Grid, Loading data with ajax and existing filters

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using a Kendo UI Grid from MVC with ajax datasource. things are working fine, however I need to show some existing filters from database. For now, I am making a call from javascript for it setting by setting the filter object. However, it is making 2 requests, first without any filters and then with filters. I want to avoid double calls.

What I have tried.

I tried setting the AutoBind to false in Html helper for kendo grid but it gives error and doesn't load anything.

Secondldly, I tried setting the Filter while creating the kendo grid with html helper, but it doesn't reflect anything on UI.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Students)
                            .Name("KendoGrid")
                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Bound(e => e.FirstName).Width(Model.FirstName).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "auto-ellipsis" });
                            })
```

.Read(read => read.Action("GetStudents", "Student").Data("BindStudents"))
)

I tried loading the loading the filters in code and applying them like
                                   .Filter(filter=>filter.Add(x=>x.Firstname contains("Mike")))
but it doesn't have any effect on kendo grid in UI.

secondly I tried using the AutoBind(false) and it just gives an error and nothing loads on page.

Comment: .Read(read => read.Action("GetStudents", "Student").Data("BindRecords"))
                            
                                    .Filter(x => x.Add(y => y.FirstName).Contains("Test"))
                                        .PageSize(20)
                                        .ServerOperation(true)
                                        .Model(model => { model.Id(e => e.ID); }
                                        )

Comment: the above code worked for me and i have also tweaked one more solutions to stop calling twice.